# Cannot boot into Windows 7 after installing 12.04

Tags: boot, wubi

I installed 12.04 by using WUBI Windows installer on my Windows 7 computer. I installed Ubuntu with the same partition (`c:\`) with Windows 7.

When I boot my computer, the boot manager does not come out and it directly boots into 12.04. So I cannot boot into Windows.

How can I make the boot manager come out to choose my boot option?

Comment: i fixed this problem.

Comment: I update grub by coomamnd [update-grub] in terminal and choose hard-disk as my primary boot device in bios

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu!  If you solved the problem yourself, could you please post the solution as an answer(instead of a comment) and accept by clicking the gray tick-mark beside the answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open a terminal, update the grub by command :
   sudo update-grub
2. Reboot the computer and go into BIOS setting (mostly is the delete button)
   choose the hard-disk as primary boot device
3. Save the setting and exit
4. The computer will be booted again, and you will find the booting manager comes out